# <transacted /> is not working in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, transactionscope, transactional

I have a database with two tables, accountsA and accountsB. I want to do some updates on both of these database tables in the same transaction scope so I used  component, but when an exception is happening in updating accountsB, the updates of accountsA is being continued, I need my database to do both updates together or none of them.

for testing that the transacted component is working correctly, I made a change in the name of the accountB table name, an exception accrued. I was expecting that the updating of accountA table will be stop, but it doesn't happened. did I do something wrong?

```
    <bean id="mysql-ds-local" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BankDB?relaxAutoCommit=true"/>
  <property name="username" value="root"/>
  <property name="password" value="osslab"/>
  <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mysql-ds-local"/>
</bean>


<camelContext id="camel-jdbc-test" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >

   <route id="main-route-jdbc">


      <from uri="timer://webinar?period=20000" /> 
       <transacted />
          <to uri="direct:reduceCredit"/>
          <to uri="direct:increaseCredit"/>
    </route>
    <route id="reduceCredit-route">
        <from uri="direct:reduceCredit"/>
        <log message="in direct accountA"/>
        <setBody>
            <constant>update accountsA set credit = credit + 1 where id = 1</constant>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="jdbc:mysql-ds-local" />
    </route>
   <route id="increaseCredit-route">
        <from uri="direct:increaseCredit"/>
        <log message="in direct accountB"/>
        <setBody>
            <constant>update accountsB set credit = credit + 1 where id = 1</constant>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="jdbc:mysql-ds-local" />
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you just omitted it, but a key element that is missing in your question is a `DataSourceTransactionManager` that makes your `DataSource` transactional.

```
<bean id="jdbcTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, you are right, I add it to my blueprint , but it does not solve the problem yet :(

Comment: Is there any other thing that i have forgot to add?

Comment: Why do you have `relaxAutoCommit=true` in your database URL? Isn't this to ignore transaction commands like `commit()` or `rollback()` although `autoCommit` is enabled?

Comment: I test it without autoCommit  but nothing changed.

Comment: Then you probably have to debug into it to find the problem. Either there is a missing piece we don't find and therefore you have no transaction at all, or your route works perfect but your database is not able to do transactions or rollbacks

Comment: your answer helped me, and also I add Required policy to my blueprint to work.